# How can I write a 'pass reference by value' wrapper in C++?

Tags: c++

I'm writing a compiler for a class, and we've decided to adopt java-like semantics for our variables. Basically, reads behave like pointer dereferences, and writes behave like pointer assignment.

So then, how can I write a wrapper class that has these semantics? Basically, every operator except assignment will be passed to the dereferenced value.

EDIT: This would want to be a template class that wraps a variable of a given type. You assign it a variable, and then use the wrapper in the place of the variable. The aim is that the wrapper containing a pointer to the original variable will have the same semantics as a java variable.

Major clarification: the compiler is translating our language down to C++, and this class is going to be used in the translated code.

Comment: I edited my original question with the response.

Comment: If you write the compiler yourself anyway, what exactly is the problem in implementing the argument passing style you want?

Comment: Are you trying to write a compiler, or trying to get C++ to work like Java?

Comment: In general it's not a good idea to port semantic and coding styles from other languages in this way, such semantic, if not really clear, will probably confuse programmers used to "normal" C++.

Comment: Are you trying to get a reseatable reference into C++? Would confuse most people!

Comment: We're not trying to modify C++, we're trying to have our compiler use these references internally to represent the language's variables. This way, we can implement java-like semantics in our little class project language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I'm totally against any attempts to turn C++ into Java (which is basically what C# is), and I'm especially puzzled by the idea of giving up value-semantics of C++, since the most useful uses of RAII essentially requires value-semantics, this is not something I would ever want to give up. But, for argument's sake, let's see what can be done.

Now, you have to realize that reference semantics almost requires some form of garbage collection. You could implement it without, but it would be very brittle and/or leaking all over the place. A simple way to do this in C++ is to use a reference counted smart pointer, i.e. boost::shared_ptr or std::tr1::shared_ptr (they are the same).

The simplest way to carry all operators of the contained type into your "ref" type is to simply provide an implicit conversion to the contained type. This way, if any operator is called, the compiler will implicitly dereference the pointer and use the underlying operator. You would probably still have to provide a get() function of some sort to do this explicitly, because the capabilities and applicability of implicit conversions doesn't work everywhere.

Then, since any operator that works on the "ref" class directly (without implicit conversion to T&) will have precedence over the operators on T&, you are free to implement these special weird-semantic operators you wish to implement.

Take a look at classes like Boost.Ref, Boost.Any and Boost.Variant, from the Boost libraries. They do similar kind of wrappers, but for slightly different (and more useful) purposes.

Comment: We're not trying to turn C++ into Java. We're trying to complete a term project, namely a compiler that translates down to C++. The variables in the language we designed have the same semantics as the variables in java, and I've been tasked with writing the wrapper class that will contain the variable class that the outputted C++ code will use.